# iOS - Distribution build fails for a Multi-Device Hybrid App error Code 65

Tags: ios, distribution, profile, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to build a Multi-Device Hybrid app in Distribution mode and am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
 ReferenceError: interval is not defined
 at throwErrorAfterDelay (C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\remoteBuild.js:249:20)
 at C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\remoteBuild.js:51:111
 at _fulfilled (C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
 at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
 at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
 at C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
 at flush (C:\Users\szumpf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -iquote /Users/shanezumpf/remote-builds/623/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/build/CordovaLib.build/Release-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/
```

This is not occurring in either Debug or Release configurations as those are building fine. I do have a provisioning profile setup for Distribution for this app.

Comment: Can you please provide the whole exception so it's possible to see in which component the exception is thrown.

Comment: Hi Ower - I've updated to include the entire exception. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which version of XCode are you working with on the Mac side?

Comment: Hi Priyank - I am using XCode 5.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error was occurring because the application ID in my config.xml file had a misspelling and did not match up with the application ID associated with the Distribution provisioning profile. I wish the error that was reported would have better explained that the provisioning profile couldn't be found for this application but at least if someone else runs into this same problem you'll have someplace to check out.